# Error when Inserting ContentDelivery : insufficient access rights on cross-reference id

Tags: apex, content

Can someone help me understand why I would get this error?  My understanding is that I should be able to insert a new ContentDelivery by using similar code:

```
ContentDistribution cd = new ContentDistribution();
cd.name = 'test';
cd.ContentVersionId = '1234567891011AA'; - using real Id
cd.PreferencesAllowOriginalDownload = false;
cd.PreferencesAllowPDFDownload = false;
cd.PreferencesAllowViewInBrowser = true;
insert cd;
```

Deliveries are enabled and I am a system admin attempting to run this code from an Anonymous block in a Sandbox.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I was using the Document Id and not the Version Id!  Boy do I feel stupid!

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that you're trying to insert Content. If so, then you need to use the [ContentVersion](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm) object. That would be the cross reference Id that the error is referring to.

From the documentation:

> To update a Salesforce CRM Content document, the user must be a member of the library with one of these library privileges enabled:
>
> - “Add Content”
> - “Add Content On Behalf of Others”
> - “Manage Library”

Comment: I'm having the insufficient access and can you please tell me how do I give the privileges enabled? I posted my question here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/334804/contentdistribution-error-insufficient-access-on-cross-reference-entity