# ContentDistribution error = INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY

Tags: files, contentversion, content, contentdistribution

EDIT:
I have enabled `Salesforce CRM Content`

[image]

[image]

I still see the insufficient access.

I'm trying to insert a record to ContentDistribution object using the following:

```
ContentDistribution cd = new ContentDistribution(
                    Name = cv.ContentDocument.Title,
                    ContentVersionId = cv.Id
                );
Insert cd;
```

But it's throwing this error, anyone have idea what causing this error?

> Insert failed. First exception on row 6; first error:
> INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access
> rights on cross-reference id: []

I see the similar issue [posted](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/312172/content-distribution-records-are-not-getting-created) but I didn't get the solution what is asking in `step 0`

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I figured out the issue.

```
Go to app launcher ==> Search for "Files"
Go to Library ==> Select the folder you uploaded files
Click on "Manage Members" button
Select the user you logged-in and select the Access 
Lastly, make sure the access has "Deliver Content"
```

How to get the Library Permission:

Setup ==> Library Permissions

[image]

Go to app launcher ==> Search for "Files"

[image]

Comment: my content documents are under-owned by me tab there is nothing under the libraries, how can I fix the same issue?